# Kali Linux Installation Attempt, Stuck in Initramfs

Tags: linux, kali-linux, grub, initramfs

I tried to install Kali Linux today. Everything went well and the installation completed without any problems. 
Though now when I start my computer I am prompted into grub.

My linux installation is on (hd0,2)

My commands in grub are:

```
set root=(hd0,2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.3.0-kali1-amd64
initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.3.0-kali1-amd64
set root=/dev/sda2
boot
```

Then I am booted into initramfs and I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shoud try this. Maybe the order is wrong.

```
grub> linux  (hd0,2)/boot/vmlinuz-4.3.0-kali1-amd64 root=/dev/sda2
grub> initrd (hd0,2)/boot/initrd.img-4.3.0-kali1-amd64
grub> boot
```

Comment: This actually worked!! Thank you so much! I have literally spent hours trying to make this work.

Comment: @Chaoswrd please mark my answer and mark your question as [solved]

Answer (score 0):

hd0,2 should be mapped to root=/dev/sda3 as per linux documentations.

Comment: Could you provide a link (and possibly a quote) to these documents?